# GREP search for a term across specific file extensions does not work

Tags: include, grep, full-text-search

I am trying to perform a grep search for a term across CSS files only in a huge directory of multiple websites.

This is what I am doing:

```
grep -irs --include=\*.css "search_term" *
```

Which is kind of what is specified in the man pages for grep. the `\*.css` to me indicates that the search be limited only to files with the .CSS extension.

As a test, I created a file called random.xxx in a test directory which has other CSS files that contain the search term. But performing the above command actually yields random.xxx as the result of the grep search instead of the CSS files.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post what you're using for "search_term"?

Comment: "quidget_caption_dt_widget" 
Why should that matter ?

Comment: If your search term had started with a "-", it could have changed the meaning for grep.  In fact, using * could do the same thing if you have files that start with "-".  Try changing * to "." (without quotes) and see if that helps.

Comment: I see, but nope changing it to .css actually yielded all possible results, that is, it included files that were not .css

Comment: No, I meant change the asterisk at the very end, not the one in the include setting.  Change that to a dot so that Bash doesn't expand it.  Bash could be expanding it into something that changes grep's settings, and using a dot instead will avoid that and have the same effect since you're using -r.  If that doesn't work, maybe try posting the exact command too, since that might help.

Comment: ok, did that too, this time it yields no results

Answer (score 0):

I always use find to grep things recursively:

ex. `find /etc/ -type f -name '*.conf' -exec grep -si 'help' {} +`

In you case replace `/etc/` by whatever path you wish, `'*.conf'` by `'*.css'`  and `'help'` by you search pattern.

It always works for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to quote the include pattern !

Like so:

```
grep --include="\*js"  foo *
```

Thanks for your question, I myself needed to escape the `*`.